# Weird Blender Rigid Body Physics

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation

I am rendering a simple rigid body simulation where a cube made up of lots of smaller cubes falls onto a plane. When I render or play it back in the viewport the physics looks really messed up. All the cubes fall to one side when they hit the plane even though there is no rotation applied. Then some of the cubes spin on their vertices and never stop. This looks similar to a past simulation I have done where cubes would fall onto a cloth. It never really worked but looks similar to the more recent simulation. Both videos and the blend files are attached.

Thanks!

[Files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1k5010v1-s54uJ3t8QZJTZuYhGwpuEVXn?usp=sharing)

Comment: Check that the object origins for all the pieces are centered within the geometry.  Applying collision forces to an off centered mesh often gives strange and inconsistent results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Allen Simpson solved it! I just correct the object origin for each of my physics objects by selecting each object and clicking `Object > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry`